# Why don't you always get points for destroying a headquarters?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've noticed that sometimes you get some points when you destroy a headquarters and sometimes you don't.

Why?

Last game I played HeadQuarter Pro, when my team was trailing, I didn't get points. When we were leading, I got 250 points. Is it related to your team leading or trailing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you get points for destroying a headquarters regardless of who is winning.  The Call of Duty Wikia has an article about Headquarters (Pro) scoring that [confirms this](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Headquarters).

In Modern Warfare 3, however, [only the first person](http://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/Headquarters_Pro) who gets to the headquarters gets the 250 points.  Is it possible you weren't first when you didn't get the points?